# Can I release what I import in a ES harmony style JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Within a script of ES Harmony style, I will decompose different styles for different components in React like the following code:

```
import React from 'react';

/** Modules */
import style from './main.css';

export class TableBody extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        /** release style */
    }
}
```

And is there any way to release the style I imported before in the method `componentWillUnmount`, so that the style of this component won't affect other components?

Before asking this question, I have tried some ways like using `delete` or assigning it with a `null` object, but both of them cannot work at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AndreLee, but I don't think it's a good way to work around it by adding hashcode, because it may get the class name losing its readability. Certainly, I may choose using postcss as a css management tool to dynamically manage this loading.

Comment: The hashcodes are added by the loader and you won't lose the readability. The CSS modules concept is invented to solve your question which is not to pollute other classes and also keep the readability.

Comment: It's not a workaround. You can check [this article](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-3-react/) for knowing more about CSS modules. BTW, you can see my webpack config, I also use the preprocessor postcss.

Comment: The quick link here of the same post above ([Reimplementing CSS Modules](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-3-react/#article-header-id-3)). The way I answered in the answer might be a **most popular** way to do with ReacJS and CSS modules recently.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `CSS modules` and `webpack`, each CSS file you imported in React components could be added a prefix or other formats you like.

The real world example will be like this `class="ChatListItem__unread___249Kw"`.

And it's hard to effect other components unless you really use `ChatListItem__unread___249Kw` in your React Components. (The **249Kw** is a hash code, in production environment, you can only keep it by the config.)

**Config for CSS Loader in webpack config**

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=1&' +
    'localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss',
  },
```

**React Component & its CSS file structure**

[image: React Component File Struc]

**And the way you import CSS file can be rewritten**

```
import React from 'react';

/** Modules */
import styles from './TableBody.css';

export class TableBody extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        /** release style */
    }

    render () {
        return <div className={styles.theClassName}></div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Good! I'll try it later, and if it works, I will tag your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @PuiManCheui no problem, feel free to ask if the answer is not clear to you.